# Unable to access the database of homestead environment (laravel) through MYSQL workbench

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, installation

Unable to access the homestead database through MYSQL workbench Please help me out to solve this issue

error messages at time of testing the connection - "**Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:33060 with user homestead**  Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0"

please take a note that
Bind address in my.cnf file is 127.0.0.1 (my.cnf file located at /etc/mysql/)
hosts file contains:  127.0.0.1   localhost   projectname  (which is located at /etc/)

I have tried changing bind address to 0.0.0.0 but it was also not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is

```
vagrant up
```

and then use these connections below for a default homestead installation.

```
Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)
Hostname: 127.0.0.1
Port: 33060
Username: homestead
Password: secret
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually I was keep trying to setup the database connectivity by just considering the homestead environment ... But on Keep searching I found one link http://www.acnenomor.com/171821p1/laravel-homestead-vagrant-box-database-problems from where I got idea and I tried once again with the data shown in attached image and it worked for me ... so I am sharing this answer in general .. it may help someone...

[image]

Please take a note that I have also tried to connect the database of Laravel homestead environment by installing all the stuffs in other system too and it was worked fine as described in the official document.. so in my case it might be the problem of some changes in configuration file of mysql or any other related environment... so please first go through the official document... http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead#daily-usage

Answer (score 1):

Try the alternate IP of  `192.168.10.10`

```
hostname  = 192.168.10.10
port = 3306
username = homestead
password = secret
```

This works for me on Windows 10 Home Version 20H2 OS Build 19042.1165 (To find this information navigate to Start, Type 'About' and click 'About your PC').

Answer (score 0):

ran into a similar problem while trying to use SQLyog on my windows machine to connect to mySQL on a Homestead environment.  I was able to resolve this issue by adding

```
skip-name-resolve
```

to the VMs /etc/mysql/my.conf file.

Apparently (according the mysql error logs) connections from the local machine were coming from '10.0.2.2', which caused the warning "IP Address '10.0.0.2' could not be resolved".

You will need to re-add this line every time you spin up the environment.